# SQL input needed to get correct output

Tags: sql, null

```
Select A.SubscriberKey, A.EventDate,B.CreatedDate
From _Click A
JOIN _ListSubscribers B
ON A.SubscriberKey = B.SubscriberKey
Where B.ListID = '10630' AND B.CreatedDate > (Select DATEADD(day,-180,getdate())) AND A.EventDate IS NULL
Group By A.SubscriberKey,B.CreatedDate, A.EventDate
```

At the moment, nothing is being returned. I want to return the Subscribers SubscriberKey(which is their email), the EventDate(the date that the click took place), and the date they were added(CreatedDate) when they have not clicked on anything. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Thanks everyone!

Comment: What defines that they have not clicked on anything?

Comment: If the subscriber has not clicked anything, then how can there be an EventDate?

Comment: @dbenham that is what we are trying to figure out. How can we show who is not clicking on anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the purpose of a GROUP BY in this case. You aren't doing any aggregation.

I believe this will give the result you are looking for.

```
select SubscriberKey,
       null as EventDate,
       CreatedDate
  from _ListSubscribers ls
 where ListID='10630'
   and CreatedDate > DateAdd( day, -180, getdate())
   and not exists( select 1 from _Click c where c.SubscriberKey = B.SubscriberKey )
```

The following query using an outer join should give the same results, and it is more similar to your original query.

```
select ls.SubscriberKey,
       c.EventDate,
       ls.CreatedDate
  from _ListSubscribers ls
  left outer join _Click c
    on c.SubscriberKey = ls.SubscriberKey
 where ListID='10630'
   and CreatedDate > DateAdd( day, -180, getdate())
   and c.EventDate is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT A.SubscriberKey, A.EventDate, B.CreatedDate 
FROM _Click A, _ListSubscribers B 
WHERE A.SubscriberKey(+) = B.SubscriberKey 
AND B.ListID = '10630' 
AND B.CreatedDate > (Select DATEADD(day,-180,getdate())) 
AND nvl(A.EventDate,null) IS NULL 
GROUP BY A.SubscriberKey,B.CreatedDate, A.EventDate
```

Comment: if he wanted a "not exists" condition then why should he select items from table `A` ? and `group by` it as well ?

Comment: We want multiple groups that will show if they have clicked greater than 10 times, between 2 and 9, 1 time, or not at all.

Comment: ANSI Joins are not useable for this application